# How do I map a value from the method request body into an API gateway mapping template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda, written in Java, that accepts a Request Object of the structure

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "value": "foobar"
}
```

When I call this Lambda through the test interface with such an object, it works fine.

I want to create an API where a `PUT` request to `/items/1` (i.e. of the form `/items/{id}`), with a request body of

```
{
  "value": "foobar"
}
```

calls this Lambda.

I have created the API resources`items`, and `{id}` appropriately.

And I have created the `PUT` method (on `/items/{id}`) and associated it to the lambda.

I have created a mapping template that maps the `id` from the path to the object.

```
{
  "id": "$method.request.path.id"
}
```

However, how do I map the `value` from the request body into the template so that I get an integration request of the form

```
{
  "id": "1",  // came from path
  "value": "foobar" // came from HTTP request body
}
```

How do I achieve this mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this in the template works.

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$')) 
{
  "id": "$method.request.path.id",
  "value": $inputRoot.value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `application/json` mapping template:

```
{
 "id": "$method.request.path.id",
 "body" : $input.json('$')
}
```

Then in your lambda: `console.log(event.body)`

[API Gateway mapping template and access logging variable reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html)

Comment: This wouldn't work for me, as the event has to be of the form `{ id, value }`, not `{ id, body.value }`

Comment: It is an example of how to read `body` using `$input.json('$')`. I see you used it in your solution.